# Wear Debris Image Processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

Wear Image1

[image: Wear Image1]

Wear Image2:

[image: Wear Image2]

Wear Image3:

[image: Wear Image3]

Wear Image4:

[image: Wear Image4]

What is the best way to extract the dark grey strands from the light green background? Also, what is the best method to compress the noise in the image in this scenario? I used the watershed algorithm, which didn't come in handy, and was thinking of trying the JSEG Algorithm. However, I am quite unfamiliar with the implementation of the JSEG Algorithm in

Comment: Hello :) You do not mean clear, can you explain more? Can you show in the picture exactly which part and how it should be found? What did you consider as noise? How did you use watershed that was not practical?

Comment: The watershed algorithm was used for the segmentation of the black strands out of the grey background. I used the skimage provided watershed option after development of markers for the image. Here, the noise refers to background, the circular rings like structure in image 3. So, the major aim is segmentation of the strands from the image assuring the noise is suppressed and the blurry strands image properties is enhanced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I obtained an interesting result by applying adaptive thresholding on the green component.

[image]