# Particle segmentation from background image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

[image: Wear Image]

Here in this image, all the black strands and small black dots you can see are particles (foreground) and the white, yellowish, greenish, grayish, and small bluish areas are the backgrounds. I am looking for an algorithm to extract the foreground and replace the background with some known color say: white. Can you please suggest to me a better solution to achieve the target?
Thank you

Comment: "better solution" implies you have one already. please present it. what became of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980618/wear-debris-image-processing ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Simple color thresholding should work here. The idea is to isolate black by using HSV color thresholding with a lower/upper threshold range to obtain a mask then `cv2.bitwise_and` to get the filtered result

You didn't specify a language so here's an implementation in Python

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
lower = np.array([0,0,0])
upper = np.array([179,255,52])

# Convert to HSV format and color threshold
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

# Display
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
# cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

HSV color thresholder script with sliders, remember to change the image file path. You can play with the sliders to refine your segmentation.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Create trackbars for color change
# Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax', 'image', 0, 179, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

# Set default value for Max HSV trackbars
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize HSV min/max values
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

while(1):
    # Get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin', 'image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin', 'image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin', 'image')
    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image')

    # Set minimum and maximum HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Convert to HSV format and color threshold
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if((phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display result image
    cv2.imshow('image', result)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```